# Swift/Quick/Nimble with async/await does not compile

Tags: swift, async-await, quick-nimble

I am trying to write a unit test using Quick/Nimble that tests an async function, as per the [Nimble documentation](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble#asyncawait-support):

```swift
await expect(await aFunctionReturning1()).to(equal(1))
```

Unfortunately this line does not compile for me.

Environment:

- Xcode 14.2
- Quick 6.1.0
- Nimble 11.2.1
- Test in a Swift Package

A minimal reproducable example is this:

```swift
import Quick
import Nimble

struct Foo {
    func bar() async -> String {
        await Task { "Hello World" }.value
    }
}

final class FooSpec: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        describe("A Foo") {
            describe("When calling Bar") {
                var foo: Foo!
                beforeEach {
                    foo = Foo()
                }
                it("Says Hello World") { await expect( await foo.bar()) == "Hello World" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This leads to `'async' call in an autoclosure that does not support concurrency`, and another warning I do not understand:
[image: Compiler error]

What am I missing?

Comment: You can watch Meet async/await. You have to convert the closures to use continuations, they can’t be mixed

Comment: There should be no need to convert closures. Nimble docs say `If you use Quick, then you don't need to do anything because as of Quick 6, all tests are executed in an async context.`.

Comment: Also, looking at Nimble's source code there are several versions of `expect` that are both async itself and have an async closure, e.g. `public func expect<T>(file: FileString = #file, line: UInt = #line, _ expression: () -> (() async throws -> T)) async -> AsyncExpectation<T>`

Comment: is titleYou refers to a chapter of the documentation that says "Expectations Using expect(...).to" and yet you use == in your code. What happens if you do `await expect( await foo.bar()).to(equal("Hello World!"))` instead?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Just tried it - same result :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit from 'AsyncSpec'.

```
final class FooSpec: AsyncSpec {...}
```

For more information: https://github.com/Quick/Quick/blob/main/Documentation/en-us/AsyncAwait.md

Answer (score -1):

After having raised the issue on the [Quick/Nimble github repo](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/issues/1035) I got feedback that suggest the [documentation](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble#asyncawait-support) is simply wrong.

Instead of using round brackets as the documentation suggests:

```swift
await expect( await foo.bar()) == "Hello World"
```

we should use curly brackets like this:

```swift
await expect { await foo.bar() } == "Hello World"
```

This line compiles and works as expected.

Comment: I would suggest that since this is a trivial mistake in the docs, the approprate and most helpful path is to fork, fix the docs, and make a pull request — not to make this a Stack Overflow entry.